# No such command 'init_db', FLASK-APP ENVIRONMENT

Tags: flask

I create a flask and when I tried to deploy it on heroku. There are errors when I try to initiate my db:

```
maiko@xxxx:~/Desktop/concevez_un_site_avec_flask-P1C1$ heroku run init
Running init on ⬢ test-ultime-maiko... up, run.7933 (Free)
Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'flask --help' for help.
```

> Error: No such command 'init_db'.

Comment: You must provide details of steps you have already done. But i assume you want to initialize the database. But first why you not using initialize migration from local dev? are you using flask-sqlalchemy and alembic for migration ?

Answer (score 0):

after that I try:
maiko@xxxx:~/Desktop/concevez_un_site_avec_flask-P1C1$ flask --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/maiko/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 556, in list_commands
rv.update(info.load_app().cli.list_commands(ctx))
File "/home/maiko/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 398, in load_app
raise NoAppException(
flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.
Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

A general utility script for Flask applications.

Provides commands from Flask, extensions, and the application. Loads the
application defined in the FLASK_APP environment variable, or from a
wsgi.py file. Setting the FLASK_ENV environment variable to 'development'
will enable debug mode.

```
$ export FLASK_APP=hello.py
$ export FLASK_ENV=development
$ flask run
```

Options:
--version  Show the flask version
--help     Show this message and exit.

Commands:
routes  Show the routes for the app.
run     Run a development server.
shell   Run a shell in the app context.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please update your question instead of posting it as an answer unless you've figured out a solution